# Jaspersoft Studio 6.16.0 on macOS Big Sur seems to be broken

Tags: eclipse, macos, jaspersoft-studio

I have installed the latest version of Jaspersoft Studio on my macOS.

Now, I have created a sample project to create a jasper report for learning.

The issues that I have noticed are given below :

1. Report templates are not updating as soon as I added some elements.
2. Drag and drop to added elements is not updating itself. I need to do random scrolling outside the template to update it.
3. Selection of an element is also not happening directly. Random Scrolling need to be done for that as well and so on..

Is there any issues of latest Jaspersoft Studio with macOS Big Sur ?

Comment: This sounds like the issues that occurred with macOS Big Sur which were fixed in Eclipse two releases ago. Maybe they are using an outdated Eclipse version or have not done the necessary adaptations for Big Sur on their side yet.

Comment: See https://community.jaspersoft.com/jaspersoft-studio/issues/13296 (in comment #22 and #37 patches are provided).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue of Jaspersoft Studio which has already been fixed:

[**[#13296] - The Jaspersoft Studio in the macOS Big Sur version is broken (does not repaint screen)**](https://community.jaspersoft.com/jaspersoft-studio/issues/13296)

See comment [#22](https://community.jaspersoft.com/jaspersoft-studio/issues/13296#comment-871206) and [#37](https://community.jaspersoft.com/jaspersoft-studio/issues/13296#comment-871916) for patches.